# Encoding.Unicode C#. Преобразование байтов в строку и обратно изменяет их первоначальный вид

Tags: c#, unicode

```
        var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\1.txt", file);

        string a1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(file);
        byte[] a2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(a1);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\2.txt", a2);
```

Содержимое файлов 1.txt и 2.txt получается различным. Каким образом можно закодировать байты в строку и раскодировать обратно не повредив их?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `Encoding.Unicode` использовать `new UnicodeEncoding(false, true, true);` и скажите, выбрасывается ли исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно считывать строку в той кодировке, в которой записан текст в `file`.